# Ключ подписи React native

Tags: react-native, expo

Хочу перейти с expo на react-native, но не могу понять как загрузить ключ подписи. Нашла что нужно ввести команду fetch:android:keystore , но куда это? Подскажите, есть ли какая нибудь статья с порядком действий? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я разобралась надо написать в командной строке : expo fetch:android:keystore